# 'What a mess' equals 'Was für ein Chaos'?

Tags: colloquial

Could you tell me, folks, if my Reverso Context translates the following English phrases into German correctly and if they are naturally used in the examples I have written?

1. What a mess — was für ein Chaos;
2. what on earth — was in aller Welt;
3. what the hell — was zum Teufel.

Examples:

1. *Was für ein Chaos ist gerade hier passiert?;*
2. *Was in aller Welt hast du mit meiner lieben Eiche getan?!*
3. *Was zum Teufel passiert nun hier?!*

Answer (score 1):

Your translation attempts are too literal. I tried to guess the English original and translated it to more natural German.

> What a mess has been happening here? — Welcher Orkan ist hier denn durchgezogen?

This is because German *Chaos* is not something that happens but an outcome. My attempt is a picture that one may use to catch the dynamic.

> What on earth have you done to my lovely oak? — Was in aller Welt hast du mit meiner schönen Eiche angestellt?

*Lovely* usually translates to *schön* in German. If you want to berate someone about what they have done, *etwas anstellen — to get into mischief* is the proper and common verb phrase. A more plain option is *machen*. Not *tun*. That latter verb is seldom used in German.

> What the hell is happening here and now? — Was zum Teufel ist hier los?

The verb phrase *los sein* conveys the chaotic aspect. No need for extra adverbials.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your #1 and #2 are more often used as interjections - and standalone.

> [enters room] "Was für ein Chaos!"

> [gets called by an unknown person who directly starts talking about a specific topic] "Was in aller Welt?! Ich denke sie sind falsch verbunden!"

Your #3, "What the hell", is more commonly used as part of a sentence. Your example given is fine.

You can translate "what the hell" with "Was zur Hölle", which is of equal meaning and usage (compared to "was zum Teufel"), but nearer to the english origin.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to translate mess/chaos. I personally like "Was für ein Durcheinander." No special reason, I just like what it means when you break it up into parts.